# Pointers not working returning address not value

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Driving me nuts. I can see no reason why the following doesn't work. It always returns the address of the value, not the value itself.

I have tried a dozen different ways of both initializing the pointers and referencing the pointers to no avail.

## Init and Loop

```
  //INIT the Motors 
  //Motor MOTORNAME(PWM_SHIELD_POSITION, POINTER TO PWM SHIELD)
    Motor LFUpper;
    Motor* ptr1 = &LFUpper;
    Motor LFLower;
    Motor* ptr2 = &LFUpper;
    Motor RFUpper;
    Motor* ptr3 = &LFUpper;
    Motor RFLower;
    Motor* ptr4 = &RFLower;
    Motor BRUpper;
    Motor* ptr5 = &BRUpper
    Motor BRLower;
    Motor* ptr6 = &BRLower
    Motor BLUpper;
    Motor* ptr7 = &BLUpper
    Motor BLLower;
    Motor* ptr8 = &BLLower


    //Init The Menu System
    Menu MenuSys( ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, ptr4, ptr5, ptr6, ptr7, ptr8);


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial2.begin(9600);
    Serial.print("HELLO");
    ptr1->INIT(FRONT_UPPER_LEFT_MOTOR);
    ptr1->INIT(FRONT_LOWER_LEFT_MOTOR);
    ptr1->INIT(FRONT_UPPER_RIGHT_MOTOR);
    ptr1->INIT(FRONT_LOWER_RIGHT_MOTOR);
    ptr1->INIT(BACK_UPPER_RIGHT_MOTOR);
    ptr1->INIT(BACK_LOWER_RIGHT_MOTOR);
    ptr1->INIT(BACK_UPPER_LEFT_MOTOR);
    ptr1->INIT(BACK_LOWER_LEFT_MOTOR);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  // Poll The Menu For Changes

  MenuSys.MenuPoll();
}
```

## Menu handler

```
Menu::Menu(Motor *LFUpper1, Motor *LFLower1, Motor *RFUpper1, Motor *RFLower1, Motor *RBUpper1, Motor *RBLower1, Motor *LBUpper1, Motor *LBLower1)
{
  LFUpper = LFUpper1;
  LFLower = LFLower1;
  RFUpper = RFUpper1;
  RFLower = RFLower1;
  LBUpper = LBUpper1;
  LBLower = LBLower1;
  RBUpper = RBUpper1;
  RBLower = RBLower1;
}

void Menu::MenuPoll()
{
  if (Serial2.available())
  {
    String readVal;
    int rw = 0;
    readVal = Serial2.readString();
    Serial.println(readVal);
    if (readVal.startsWith("W"))
    {
      rw = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      rw = 0;
    }
    int MenuCommand = readVal.substring(1, 4).toInt();
    int Value =  readVal.substring(4, readVal.length()).toInt();

    MenuHandler(rw, MenuCommand, Value);
  }
}

void Menu::MenuHandler(int rw, int MenuCommand, int Value)
{
  Serial.println(rw);
  Serial.println(MenuCommand);
  Serial.println(Value);
  switch (MenuCommand) {
      case 111:
      if (rw == 1)
       {
        Serial.print(LFUpper->pwmMIN);
        LFUpper->pwmMIN = Value;
       }
```

The line `Serial.print(LFUpper->pwmMIN);` does not print the correct value

Comment: What value is it printing and what value are you expecting

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are taking addresses of wrong objects.

```c++
Motor LFUpper;
Motor* ptr1 = &LFUpper;
Motor LFLower;
Motor* ptr2 = &LFUpper;
Motor RFUpper;
Motor* ptr3 = &LFUpper;
```

probably should be

```c++
Motor LFUpper;
Motor* ptr1 = &LFUpper;
Motor LFLower;
Motor* ptr2 = &LFLower;
Motor RFUpper;
Motor* ptr3 = &RFUpper;
```

Also your `ptr1->INIT()` blocks all call `INIT` on `ptr1`.

Comment: Appoligies about that I copied and pasted from my temporary window I had already fixed those issues after I fixed that it still wasn't working I found a few other problems that I thought would fix it and actually made it so it worked the first time through the loop but then it break.. for example if the value it was looking at was 123 the first time through I would get 123 and the next I was getting like 529000 and I didn't do any operations on the data between cycles. So I went back to square 1 and eliminated all of the nested pointers passed as function arguments and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few other problems that I thought would fix it and actually made it so it worked the first time through the loop but then it break.. for example if the value it was looking at was 123 the first time through I would get 123 and the next I was getting like 529000 and I didn't do any operations on the data between cycles. So I went back to square 1 and eliminated all of the nested pointers passed as function arguments and now it works